# How to apply css modules in dangerously set Inner html in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have html stored in the database and I want to render it on my react page and for that I used

```
import low from "../css/low.module.css";
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}/>
```

and this works perfectly. I am also using css modules and I want this html (from database) to detect the css.
I can not use `cssFileName.className` as it is stored in the database.

For example

```
data = <div class="news_page_detail">
<p class="news_page_detail">My Para1<br class="Pc_only">My Para2</p>
<p class="news_page_detail">My Para3</p>
<p class="news_page_detail">My Para4
</p>
<a href="/someLink" class="btn-pink-b ovbg ">
<div class="btn-inner">
<div class="ovbg_pink"></div>
<span class="btn-pink-b-txt">My span1</span>
</div>
</a>
```

Is there any solution so that I apply the css modules here. I dont want to import the css as conventional way because they are interfering with the other css.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) library. I have used it and I can style inline my content.

```
 import parse from 'html-react-parser'

 <div
      style={{ color: 'black' }}
 >
     {parse(item?.content)}
 </div>
```

Comment: Lets say I have className  `myClassName` in low.module.css and `data` = `<div class="myClassName"></div>`. So How I can apply this css ?

Comment: try `<div className="myClassName>{parse(data}</div>`